# nvidia prime dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr, nvidia-prime

After I fix `nvidia-prime` black screen issue [Solving the Ubuntu 14.04 – NVIDIA 346 – nvidia-prime black screen issue](http://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/) I can't set up dual monitors. In one time I have enable only one monitor. How can I set back dual monitors?

Comment: What did you try so far to set up dual screens, e. g. `nvidia-settings`?

Comment: I upgrade my Ubuntu to 14.10 and now the solution above doesn't work. Therefore I open a new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602013/how-to-get-nvidia-346-driver-with-optimus-to-work-on-ubuntu-14-10