# How to get nvidia-346 driver with optimus to work on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-optimus

I'm using notebook with optimus technology (Asus K73SV). I have installed proprietary nvidia 346 (346.47-0ubuntu4~xedgers14.10.1 from ppa xorg-edgers) on Ubuntu 14.10. If I select to use an intel driver (using nvidia-prime), the intel graphics card works fine. But if I try to use nvidia driver I can't run lightdm service (black screen).

My Xorg.0.log file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10688891

There is a statement with following error in Xorg.0.log file:

```
[    28.650] (EE) intel(G1): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[    28.650] (II) intel(G1): [drm] Contents of '/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/clients':
[    28.650] (II) intel(G1): [drm] a dev    pid    uid  magic
[    28.650] (II) intel(G1): [drm] 
[    28.650] (II) intel(G1): [drm] y   0  1492     0          0
[    28.650] (II) intel(G1): [drm] y   0  1492     0          0
[    28.650] (EE) intel(G1): Failed to claim DRM device.
[    28.650] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
```

I found similar topic at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/816599/prime-switching-to-nvidia-creates-black-screen/ but without solution right now.

Is there some workaround how to fix it without downgrade nvidia driver?

Comment: take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/601894/nvidia-840m-driver-problem-with-kubuntu-14-10?noredirect=1#comment840106_601894

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues in the past and have never been completely able to figure out. It also appears that some fixes don't work for others. The only was I have ever been able to get the newer drivers to work on my own system is by removing nvidia-prime and installing bumblebee to control the switching from Intel to NVIDIA.